# SVG - store some extra data which can be extracted using javascript

Tags: javascript, svg

Sorry for my ignorance, I am not too familiar using SVGs. I have an SVG file, but I need to store some extra information about. Things such as a Title for the image and a Description. After searching StackOverflow I noticed you can insert a tag called **metadata** into an svg to store some custom data. I didn't really understand how to implement it so decided to go to the w3 specification for it at https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/metadata.html but it seems metatadata is no longer supported. If that is the case, how can I store some additional information inside of the SVG file so it can be accessed using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

The link in your question says metadata's description has [moved to here](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#MetadataElement). Metadata is no more or less supported by browsers today than it's always been.

If you're using SVG embedded in html you can also use [data- attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes).

Answer (score 0):

Note also that SVG has built-in elements for providing a title and description.

```
<svg>
  <title>Ukulele Lady</title>
  <desc>A lady sitting on a high-backed chair playing a ukulele to an attentive dachshund.<desc>
  ...
</svg>
```

https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/single-page.html#struct-DescriptionAndTitleElements